# 'Member not found' javascript error while open document link with IE browser

Tags: member

In my HTML page there is two link of the documents.

Like as below:

**Link 1**

**Link 2**

When i click on link "Link 1" , it open the document in new windows , now i will minimize it , and again i click on "Link 2" with out closing the previous window. it will give me the  'Member not found' javascript error in IE 6/7/8 browsers

After i had goggling for this issue , i got the solution , check it for below

//below code is before solution:

```
var viewerURL = "URl";
win = window.open(viewerURL, 'subWindow', 'directories=no, status=no');
win.focus();
```

//after applying the solution code is like below

```
var progressMsgURL = "url";
win = window.open(viewerURL, 'subWindow', 'directories=no, status=no');
if(win==null || win.closed)
{
 win.focus();
}
```

right now above code is not  giving me any java script error in IE 6/7/8.

but now it will stop the focus of windows in all the browsers.It means that when i open one Link 1 documents in one windows and then minimize it and now again open the Link 2 document ,it will open it but that newly opened windows is refreshing  but it will remain in minimize mode, user does not getting any intimate about that.

i want the expected solution is :
Not giving me 'Member not found' javascript error in IE 6/7/8 browsers, as well as win.focus(); is also working in all the browsers.

pls help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in Advance
Yatin Baraiya

Answer (score 0):

If you need the last clicked URL window to have the focus then your code should be

```
var progressMsgURL = "url";
win = window.open(viewerURL, 'subWindow', 'directories=no, status=no');
if(win!=null)
{
 win.focus();
}
```